# Product currency could not working, i getting error in Modx System

Tags: php, modx

I have use Modx CMS. today i get this error. Bellow my error line.

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /var/www/bottega/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/63.include.cache.php on line 24

```
$id = $row['id'];
$product = $modx->getObject('modResource',  $id)->Product;
$price = $product->sm_price;
$currency = (int)$product->sm_currency; //$currency out is 153 dynamically
$currency =  $modx->getObject('modResource', trim($currency))->get('longtitle'); //this line number 24
```

Actually, when i initialize manually `$currency` variable `153` then this problem solve. but when i use `$currency` initialize from database `(int)$product->sm_currency;` it show error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /var/www/bottega/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/63.include.cache.php on line 24
```

For example `$currency` variable manually initialize with 153

```
$id = $row['id'];
$product = $modx->getObject('modResource',  $id)->Product;
$price = $product->sm_price;
$currency = 153; 
$currency =  $modx->getObject('modResource', trim($currency))->get('longtitle'); //this line number 24
```

Now work fine

Comment: Well, what is before, on and after that line?

Comment: i got this error in home page. Now just show one line error

Comment: Which snippet has ID 63 in your installation?

Comment: Please remove the links to your site. They don't help here.

Comment: can you show your `var_dump($product)` result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by a change of the PHP version by your hosting company.

Since you added some code in your question: Please check whether an object exist, before you use it (sample below).

```
$id = $row['id'];
$productRes = $modx->getObject('modResource',  $id);
if ($productRes && $productRes->Product) {
    $product = $productRes->Product;
    $price = $product->sm_price;
    $currency = (int)$product->sm_currency;
    $currencyRes = $modx->getObject('modResource', $currency);
    if ($currencyRes) {
        $currency = currencyRes->get('longtitle');
    }
}
```